# How to force unzip listing to use unicode UTF-8

Tags: macos, shell, unicode, zip, unzip

**ZIP**

```
zip -r --symlinks ../a.zip a a.txt 
  adding: a/šáčžřŠÁČÝŘŽÚ§/ (stored 0%)
```

Filename is stored properly in unicode.

**LIST**

```
unzip -l ../a.zip 
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  03-11-2021 14:40   a/s??a??c??z??r??S??A??C??Y??R??Z??U??§/
```

unzip list prints crapy chars.

The filenames are stored in zip correctly in unicode because the unzip restores them properly but I need to show the zip listing in correct unicode chars.

How do I print the listing in correct unicode? Has this anything to do with shell settings?

Comment: This is not  programing question. Try asking on [su].

Answer (score -2):

On Ubuntu you can use patched p7zip instead of unzip.

Comment: I need to use standard MacOS tools :-( This will be generic distribution.